# how to properly assign pthread idle status inside a threadpool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, pthreads, threadpool

I am using the below code to create a threadpool, but I can not find a proper place to set thread idle state, how to modify the below code so that I can pick up which thread is busy?

```
std::vector<structThread> preallocatedThreadsPool;
std::queue<int> tcpQueue;
struct structThread {
    pthread_t thread;
    bool idleState;
};
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t condition_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* threadFunctionUsedByThreadsPool(void *arg);
std::atomic<bool> stopCondition(false);



main () {
   preallocatedThreadsPool.resize(preallocatThreadsNumber); // create a threadpoOl.           
     for(structThread &i : preallocatedThreadsPool) {
         pthread_create(&i.thread, NULL, threadFunctionUsedByThreadsPool, NULL);
     }
       

  // when a event happened
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); // one thread mess with the queue at one time
  tcpQueue.push(even);
  pthread_cond_signal(&condition_var);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

}


void* threadFunctionUsedByThreadsPool(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while (!stopCondition) {
           // wait for a task to be queued
       while (tcpQueue.empty() && !stopCondition) {
           pthread_cond_wait(&condition_var, &mutex); // wait for the signal from other thread to deal with client otherwise sleep
       }
       if (stopCondition == false) {

           newevent = tcpQueue.front();
           tcpQueue.pop();
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  // exit lock while operating on a task
           // do even related task
           pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  // re-acquire the lock
       }
 
    }
   // release the lock before exiting the function
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   return NULL;
}
```

The code above, each time when a new even pop from the queue, how do I find a way to set corresponding thread's intestate to busy? Because currently, each time a task come, system just randomly assign a task to the thread in my threadpool, how do I change the code so that my threadpool can memorize each thread idle state

Comment: Don't assign tasks to threads.  Put them in a single queue and let threads take items from the queue when they are ready.

Comment: Dont set thread idle state. When the thread is idle it should wait. You can use a condition_var for this. I see you're mixing POSIX/C library with C++. C++ has it's own library that interfaces with POSIX and it is much simpler. Have a look at my example: 
https://github.com/doa379/libqueue-

Answer (score 0):

> The code above, each time when a new even pop from the queue, how do I find a way to set corresponding thread's intestate to busy?

That's very easy: just set `idleState = false` before you `pthread_mutex_unlock` and back to `true` after you re-lock the mutex (after event-related code is done).

> Because currently, each time a task come, system just randomly assign a task to the thread in my threadpool

That *is* the correct way to use a thread pool. Anything else you want to do is likely to add bugs.